# Unable to send a text containing ".xyz"

Tags: sms

I discovered this while trying to send friends URLs ending in .xyz. The texts appeared to be sent, but no one was receiving them. At first I assumed it was because the link was blacklisted somewhere along the line, but further experimenting showed that I cannot send a text containing the string ".xyz" anywhere in the message.

I **am** able to receive such texts though.

The phone is a moto g(7) power running Android 10. A friend has a Samsung Galaxy S10E and also can't send .xyz.

Sending other tlds such as ".com" etc works fine. Any guesses about what's going on?

Comment: .xyz domains are often used for distributing malware. May be your mobile network provider therefore filters out such messages as a form of "anti-virus service"?

Answer (score 0):

This depends of your phone carrier provider because actually I tested it with my orange carrier lines and sent an sms with url **.xyz** extension and received it. It could be also that your AV is restricting such extension. [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao1a0OPcKzs9gzNJ1ia5sOO8AcWW)